# Proper use of ETS give away function

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

So this is my code :

```
defmodule Parent do
  def arun(pid) do
    :ets.new(:my_table,[:named_table, :set, :public, read_concurrency: true])
    :ets.give_away(:my_table, pid, [])
  end

  def receiver do
    pid = spawn(fn -> arun(self()) end)
    receive do
      {'ETS-TRANSFER',_,_,_} ->
        IO.puts "ets got transferred"
      _ ->
        IO.puts "I dont know what happened"
    end
  end
end
```

But when I am trying to compile this runtime error is coming .

```
iex(31)> Parent.receiver

17:37:19.183 [error] Process #PID<0.204.0> raised an exception
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.give_away(:my_table, #PID<0.204.0>, [])
    parent.ex:4: Parent.arun/1
```

Also can someone tell me proper way to make a ets table and give its ownership to other process ?
I am trying to this :
Parent process will create a asynchronous task which will create a ets table and then this task/process will return ownership back to the parent process.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is on this line:

```
    pid = spawn(fn -> arun(self()) end)
```

You're trying to spawn a new process which calls a function with the parent pid as the argument, but since the call to `self()` is *inside* the spawn, you get the child pid instead.  (And if a process tries to give away an ETS table to itself, it gets an "argument error".)

Try this:

```
    parent = self()
    pid = spawn(fn -> arun(parent) end)
```